# Как на PHP определить часовой пояс по IP адресу посетителя?

Tags: php, timezone

Можно ли на PHP как то по IP адресу посетителя определить часовой пояс(например чтобы для IP адресов Москвы определялось +3).
Я понимаю что можно на JavaScript определить, но можно ли прямо на PHP по IP?

Comment: Не нужно ничего определять по IP - прокси, куча адресатов на одном IP

Comment: Прокси это понятно, а как куча адрессатов на одном ip влияет?

Comment: Наверное Вадим имел ввиду что на 1 прокси могут сидеть несколько пользователей при этом из разных уголков планеты и получается у них у всех будет часовой пояс определяться как у прокси.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае есть два неплохих варианта

**Вариант 1**:

Получить смещение часового пояса клиента на самой клиентской части и кинуть его на бек.

К примеру:

```
const offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(offset); // возвращает разницу по гринвичу в минутах
```

Плюсы: Вне зависимости от айпи юзера мы получим его часовой пояс.

Минусы: Юзер легко может поменять время на клиенте и у нас будут ложные данные

**Вариант 2:**

Юзать сторонний сервис для получения данной инфы по апи, благо их сейчас достаточно, не буду наводить конкретные примеры сервисов и реализации самого запроса - эта инфа и так очень легко гуглится.

Плюсы: Простота реализации.

Минусы: Скорее всего вы не угадаете часовой пояс. Некоторые юзеры действительно используют прокси\VPN и тд. из-за чего, у вас будет часовой пояс того региона, кому принадлежит айпи с которого пришел к вам юзер.

**Итоги:** если есть возможность - используйте первый вариант, еще лучше дать возможность юзеру самому выбрать свой часовой пояс.